# Must UTF-8 binaries include /utf8 in the binary literal in Erlang?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, binary, erlang

In erlang, when defining a UTF-8 binary string, I need to specify the encoding in the binary literal, like this:

```
Star = <<"★"/utf8>>.
> <<226,152,133>>
io:format("~ts~n", [Star]).
> ★
> ok
```

But, if the `/utf8` encoding is omitted, the unicode characters are not handled correctly:

```
Star1 = <<"★">>.
> <<5>>
io:format("~ts~n", [Star1]).
> ^E
> ok
```

Is there a way that I can create literal binary strings like this without having to specify `/utf8` in every binary I create? My code has quite a few binaries like this and things have become quite cluttered. Is there a way to set some sort of default encoding for binaries?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking but you don't need to include /utf8 for every character, you can also do it on a string basis. So this is legal <<"åäö"/utf8>>.

Comment: I should have provided a better example. I was aware that it works on a string basis, but I often have many separate strings in one block of code (especially in my tests).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably a result of the ambiguity of Erlang strings and lists. When you enter `<<"★">>`, what Erlang is actually seeing is `<<[9733]>>`, which, of course, is just a list containing an integer. As such, I believe Erlang in this case would encode 9733 as an integer, most likely with 16-bits (though I could certainly be wrong on that).

The `/utf8` flag indicates to Erlang that this is supposed to be a UTF8 string, and thus gives a hint to the VM about how best to encode the integer it encounters.

Comment: Note: Erlang does not accept the syntax `<<[9733]>>`, but said syntax is equivalent to your example. The binary syntax for strings (`<<"foo">>`) probably assumes binary syntax (`<<"foo"/binary>>`), and if so would consume the string contents byte-by-byte. Also notable, `<<9733/utf8>>` also produces the string you expect, so the utf8 flag can be used for more than just strings.

Comment: Erlang actually treats `<<"★">>` as `<<9733>>` (not `<<[9733]>>` which, as the previous comment notes, produces a syntax error). The [default size for each integer segment in a binary literal](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html#segments) is 8 bits, and the compiler uses the least-significant bits of the integer when constructing the binary literal, so this is the same as `<<(9733 rem 256)>>`, which is `<<5>>`.