# Use unicode characters correctly

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am attempting to save a binary with characters of any type for example:

```
$  LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V9.2  (abort with ^G)
1> TextBinaryWithSpecialChar =  <<" Hey, If you’re down, I’m here to help">>.                    
<<32,72,101,121,44,32,73,102,32,121,111,117,25,114,101,32,
  100,111,119,110,44,32,73,25,109,32,104,101,114,...>>
2>
```

How can I make it save just what I want: **<<" Hey, If you’re down, I’m here to help">>**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must UTF-8 binaries include /utf8 in the binary literal in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315971/must-utf-8-binaries-include-utf8-in-the-binary-literal-in-erlang)

Answer (score 3):

```
1> <<"you’re"/utf8>>. 
<<121,111,117,226,128,153,114,101>>
```

In UTF-8, a "Right Single Quotation Mark" is represented by three bytes:

```
             Hex 
          Notation
           -------
1st byte:    E2 => E=14    2 
                   1110  0010 = 226

2nd byte:    80 =>  8     0
                   1000  0000 = 128

3rd byte:    99 =>  9     9
                   1001  1001 = 153
```

I don't know how erlang gets `25` for a "Right Single Quotation Mark" when you don't specify utf8 for the binary.  (14 + 2 + 9 = 25?)

In erlang, `"abc"` is just a shortcut for the list `[97,98,99]`, similarly with binaries:

```
5> <<97,98,99>>.
<<"abc">>
```

Whether the shell displays characters or numbers is irrelevant:

```
6> <<97,98,99>> == <<"abc">>.
true
```

Comment: "Right Single Quotation Mark" becomes 25 because Erlang truncates values in binaries to bytes unless otherwise specified. Its codepoint is U+2019, so it gets truncated to `16#19`, which is equal to 25.

Comment: @legoscia, Wouldn't that be truncating by digits--not bytes?  2019 in binary is: `0000 0111 1110 0011`.  I don't see how truncating that--any way you slice it--will come up with `0001 1001` (or 25).

Comment: 2019 is in hex, so `0010 0000 0001 1001` in binary.

Comment: @legoscia, `2019 is in hex` - Thanks.